# Getting error in setting up Rest API for Youtrack

Tags: php, rest, youtrack

Anyone have tried using https://github.com/nepda/youtrack?
I'm trying to setup it but getting error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'YouTrack\Exception' not found in D:\wamp\www\flow\libs\YouTrack\Connection.php on line 117
```

the library can be found at https://github.com/nepda/youtrack
so what I did is downloaded it and do test :

```
include_once './config/config_inc.php';
include_once './libs/parser.php';

require_once("./libs/YouTrack/Connection.php");
try {
    $youtrack = new YouTrack\Connection(
        YOUTRACK_URL,
        YOUTRACK_USERNAME . 'invalid',
        YOUTRACK_PASSWORD
    );
    echo 'Login correct.' . PHP_EOL;
} catch (\YouTrack\IncorrectLoginException $e) {

    echo 'Incorrect login or password.' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: looks like an error in the YouTrack source-code, maybe checkout a previous version

Comment: yay, thanks for the answer, got older version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php). In this case a very simple setup would be:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class)
{
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    require_once $path . '.php';
}

try {
    $youtrack = new YouTrack\Connection(
        YOUTRACK_URL,
        YOUTRACK_USERNAME . 'invalid',
        YOUTRACK_PASSWORD
    );
    echo 'Login correct.' . PHP_EOL;
} catch (\YouTrack\IncorrectLoginException $e) {

    echo 'Incorrect login or password.' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

(This will work with version 1.5.3 of [nepda/youtrack-client](https://github.com/nepda/youtrack-client)).

I've added a readme section "[Standalone setup with composer](https://github.com/nepda/youtrack-client#standalone-setup-with-composer)".

Please checkout composer for managing your packages. Composer comes with a good implementation of autoloading.